# "Pitch" when we talk about /computer/ monospaced fonts

Tags: fonts, terminology, monospace

> Pitch is the number of (monospaced) letters, numbers and spaces in one inch (25.4 mm) of running text, that is, characters per inch (abbreviated cpi). The pitch was most often used as a measurement of the size of typewriter fonts as well as those of impact printers used with computers.
>
> The most widespread fonts in typewriters are 10 and 12 pitch, called Pica and Elite, respectively.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_(typewriter)

But what about computer fonts?

Here are, from top to bottom: Courier New, JetBrains Mono NL, Noto Sans Mono, and the last one is Consolas. All fonts are 12 pt size, and the frame is 1 inch width.

[image]

As you can see, all fonts except Consolas have the same CPI ratio, 10:1, but I don't think we can really call them *10-pitch fonts*, because the number of characters you can put on 1-inch line depends on the font size (that is, if you reduce the font size from 12 pt to 10 pt, you can put more of them on the same line, of course). And by the way, I'm not even sure that letters produced by typewriters were really 12 pt size.

So my question: is there an established term like "computer pitch", which will be understood by people like

> *10-computer-pitch font* is a font whose character-per-inch ratio **for 12-pt font size** is 10:1

?

Comment: Interesting question...

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is that we should talk not about font family but about both font family and font size. That's it!

- 10-point Courier New is a 12-pitch font
- 12-point Courier New is a 10-pitch font
- 12-point PragmataPro is a 12-pitch font

Comment: I think this misses the point of the question: How does one *define* a pitch for a computer font and is there a common term for that definition